# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Rendering Odd JSON Body - Breaks Angular HttpClient

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0, using MVC controllers to handle REST API requests.  When using Chrome to just look at the responses, everything looks normal, but when I try to consume them using Angular 2 HttpClient, it errors (and frustratingly won't tell me why).  I think I may know why, though.  When I use Fiddler to inspect the raw HTTP response coming from my ASP.NET app, the response body is preceded by "f6" and followed by "0".  Why would it do that?  Here is an example of the response I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2017 17:14:27 GMT

f6
[{"Id":1,"name":"Hello World"}]
0
```

**FOLLOW-UP:** I now know why it does this.  It is using "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", and the leading f6 is stating the size of the chunk, and the 0 at the end is indicating the final 0 length chunk.

Here is my Angular service in which I make the call back to the API.  Sorry it is a bit convoluted... using generics to make my code more concise.  It never hits the return statement.  Bombs somewhere in the .get() call must be.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    }

    protected getAPIObject<T>(targetUrl: string): Promise<Array<T>> {
        return this._http.get(targetUrl).toPromise().then(data => {
            return data as Array<T>;
        });
    }
}
```

And, also not very interesting, my Startup.cs class for the web service that the above Angular is attempting to "GET" (**SPOILER**: I was wrong.  See answer below for why this was the area of interest!)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.Configure<SqlStatementSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqlStatements"));
        services.AddSingleton<IObjectRepository, ObjectRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before using Angular, does API return expected result, if you use PostMan or Fiddler to post and get the data?

Comment: Yes, even when I enter the API URL in Chrome, and watch through fiddler, I'll see this same format in the response.  Chrome seems to know how to handle it.

Comment: Btw, I have proven that the HttpClient does work, by making a direct call to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.  It handles that beautifully.

Comment: Could you show us your angular code?

Comment: Edited my above post.  Also interesting... I just used fiddler to compose a request to the URL  (comment above) on which the HttpClient works, and it has leading and trailing characters to  Something like: "3d67[{JSON attribuges here}]0".  Maybe I'm off on the wrong foot with that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... and I was way off track; the "f6" and "0" surrounding my JSON were because it was using "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" (note added to original question).  What was causing my problems was that I had not setup CORS properly.  Below is my correction of this mistake.  I actually had tried setting up CORS once before and it didn't work... because I had added "UseCors" after I added "UseMvc" and order matters when you are chaining middleware together.  Btw, I'm not recommending using AllowAnyOrigin for production, this was my development fix.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", policy => policy.AllowAnyOrigin());
        });

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.Configure<SqlStatementSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqlStatements"));
        services.AddSingleton<IObjectRepository, ObjectRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```